# get search results then populate page without refresh

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am not realy sure where to start. I have a page setup to search for members in my admin panel. I am trying to find a way to get search results without refreshing the page when clicking a button. I already have a file that searches the db which is a seperate php file. The page the search box is on is also a php file. I have spent days googling and reading posts on here with little success. All i want is a button that when clicked will search the db for the member name in the search box then populate a list on the same page without refreshing the page. any tips would be much appreciated. this is my searchbox code below.

```
        <div class="search-box">
        <input type="text" autocomplete="off" class="inputboox1" tabindex="1" placeholder="Search Member..." />
        <div class="result" style='overflow:auto; width:190px;max-height:100px;'></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: ajax is what you will need to use for this

Comment: i know but i am not sure where to start, thanks

Comment: You start by Googling "Javascript Ajax".

Comment: You can use an `onclick` event on the button, and then handle all the stuff within an AJAX call.

Comment: ive been doing that for days, thats why i am asking here

Comment: So you know ajax, but not how to use it?

Answer (score 3):

You should use [ajax](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp).

1. Create your HTML form
2. Add a `click` event on your submit button
3. Call your backend endpoint from javascript
4. Display the response

Here is an example from w3schools:

**HTML:**

```
<html>
  <head>
  <script>
    function showResult(str) {
      if (str.length==0) { 
        document.getElementById("livesearch").innerHTML="";
        document.getElementById("livesearch").style.border="0px";
        return;
      }
      if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      } else {  // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (this.readyState==4 && this.status==200) {
          document.getElementById("livesearch").innerHTML=this.responseText;
          document.getElementById("livesearch").style.border="1px solid #A5ACB2";
        }
      }
      xmlhttp.open("GET","livesearch.php?q="+str,true);
      xmlhttp.send();
    }
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <form>
      <input type="text" size="30" onkeyup="showResult(this.value)">
      <div id="livesearch"></div>
    </form>

  </body>
</html>
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
$xmlDoc=new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load("links.xml");

$x=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('link');

//get the q parameter from URL
$q=$_GET["q"];

//lookup all links from the xml file if length of q>0
if (strlen($q)>0) {
  $hint="";
  for($i=0; $i<($x->length); $i++) {
    $y=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('title');
    $z=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('url');
    if ($y->item(0)->nodeType==1) {
      //find a link matching the search text
      if (stristr($y->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue,$q)) {
        if ($hint=="") {
          $hint="<a href='" . 
          $z->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . 
          "' target='_blank'>" . 
          $y->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . "</a>";
        } else {
          $hint=$hint . "<br /><a href='" . 
          $z->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . 
          "' target='_blank'>" . 
          $y->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . "</a>";
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

// Set output to "no suggestion" if no hint was found
// or to the correct values
if ($hint=="") {
  $response="no suggestion";
} else {
  $response=$hint;
}

//output the response
echo $response;
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use ajax for this, try something like that with jQuery:

```
var searchValue = $('#idOfSearchField').val();
$.ajax({
    url: 'search.php',
    data: {
      text: searchValue
    },
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
        $('.result').html(data);
    }
});
```

You can even use "keydown" events to send queries as the user types

Comment: thank you kotapeter and Mokkun for your help, ive been struggling over this for sometime now. not sure why someone would vote me down, my question was to the point and was understandable and was only asking for your help.